# Authentication using AngularJs and UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to write a authentication module for my application, following examples from online tutorials.

Using `console.log`, it works fine. If I use `$state.go()` I am getting infinite loop which is throwing maximum call stack size exceeded.

Where would my mistake be?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function ($rootScope, $state) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {

        var learner = toState.data.isLoggedIn && toState.data.role == 'learner';
        var trainer = toState.data.isLoggedIn && toState.data.role == 'trainer';
        var guest = !toState.data.isLoggedIn && toState.data.role == 'guest';

        if (learner) {
            console.log('learner');
        }
        else if (trainer) {
            console.log('trainer');
        }
        else {
            $state.go('home');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: @NafeezAbrar: thanks for improving the post, but note that inline code spans (`like this`) should only be used for code within sentences, not for highlighting. See [this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990/2074608) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to a known issue in ui-router since angular 1.3.4 or so. See here for workarounds: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/600

I also had this issue, and could fix it by using the other version of .otherwise which takes a function:

replace:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
```

with:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise( function($injector, $location) {
        var $state = $injector.get("$state");
        $state.go("home");
    });
```

Comment: I am using the exact same pattern and it works, so your code above is ok. The only difference I see in your code snippet is that I call event.preventDefault() before $state.go('home'), but that is most probably not of relevance. This means the problem must be somewhere else in your code or specific versions of angular.js and ui-router. Sorry, can't really help without more information.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying back. I tried event.preventDefault() before $state.go('home') and still loop is going on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514409/authentication-based-on-role-angularjs-ui-router                                                                                                     Here is my latest code. kindly have a look and guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: when I look at your code in the other post I see the exact issue I posted in this answer here (the github link):  try to replace your line: $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
with: 
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise( function($injector, $location) {
        var $state = $injector.get("$state");
        $state.go("home");
    });

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an if clause to exclude action if toState === 'home'

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function ($rootScope, $state) {

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {
    if(toState.name === 'home'){
        return;
    }
    var learner = toState.data.isLoggedIn && toState.data.role == 'learner';
    var trainer = toState.data.isLoggedIn && toState.data.role == 'trainer';
    var guest = !toState.data.isLoggedIn && toState.data.role == 'guest';

    if (learner) {
        console.log('learner');
    }
    else if (trainer) {
        console.log('trainer');
    }
    else {
        $state.go('home');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});

}]);
```